# jquery change placehoder input from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, I want a command in the dropdown that I created. 
dropdown and input code example:

```
<select name="field" id="list_field">
                  <option value='all'>All Field</option>
                  <option value="A" >AAA</option>
                  <option value="B" >BBB</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="add text in here..">
```

if I want a select dropdown selected, then the placeholder in the textbox also changes.
is a case in point: 
If I select the dropdown "A", the placeholder will be changed to "AAAxxxx".
how jquery or javascript code to perform these commands? is there anything that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $("#list_field").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'A'){
        $("input[name=keyword]").attr('placeholder', 'AAA');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#list_field').change(function(){
   $('input[name="keyword"]').attr("placeholder", $(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2FVf/)**

Comment: @Minlind people become jealous and they downvote...:/